# Bootstrap 5.2 Tooltip Slides left with overflow and smaller screen width

Tags: html, asp.net, .net-core, bootstrap-5

I don't have sample code at the moment in a state I can share, but I am using Bootstrap 5.2's Tooltips on a site I'm working on.

I have a button that's on the very right side of the screen, that displays a tooltip.  Works fine when the screen is full size.  However when I shrink my browser screen down to something around 765px in width of the html element, the overflow horizontal scroll bar appears and the tool tip starts moving far to the left the more narrow I make my screen.  The tool tip won't stay attached to the button.

I've tried messing with the boundary stuff but I think I'm doing it wrong.

... a few divs wrapping the below code ...

```
<span>
  <span>
    <button id="buttonwithtooltip1" class="btn btn-outline-dark" type="button" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="bottom" data-bs-custom-class="custom-tooltip" data-bs-trigger="hover" data-bs-title="Hide the display area shown below, of all selected filters.">Collapse All</button>
  </span>

  <span>
    <button id="buttonwithtooltip2" class="btn btn-outline-dark" type="button" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="bottom" data-bs-custom-class="custom-tooltip" data-bs-trigger="hover" data-bs-title="Show the display area shown below, of all selected filters.">Collapse All</button>
  </span>
</span>
```